# php echo quotation marks error

Tags: php, quoting

I'm having hard time with quotation marks. I have this line of code;

```
echo "<a href='$bName'_read.php?bid='$bid'&id='$next_id[id]'>NEXT</a>";
```

with 3 variables, `$bName`,`$bid`, and `$next_id[id]`.

There is something wrong with the quotations I've used. I also tried this;

```
echo "<a href='".$bName."_read.php?bid=".$bid."&id=".$next_id['id']."'">";
```

but it's still not working.

Can anyone explain how quoting works in this case please?

Comment: Looks like a proper job for [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) instead

Comment: None of those variables need to be quoted inside that string, but `$bname` should be `{}` enclosed as `href='{$bname}_read.php?...` and the entire `href` string should be quoted

Comment: For readability and unambiguity, they will all benefit from `{}` As in `echo "<a href='{$bName}_read.php?bid={$bid}&id={$next_id['id']}'>NEXT</a>";`

Comment: only the url needs quotes. you might want to literally write down an example output, if this is not immediately obvious to you...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski expanding on the subjective readability you mentioned here. That is one unreadable mess :)

Comment: @PeeHaa Meh - it's messy no matter which approach - interpolation, concatenation, sprintf, they're all ugly for a url.

Comment: The documentation page of [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) contains all the answers you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to put single quotes around every PHP variable. It should make sense in HTML instead, for example;

```
echo "<a href='{$bName}_read.php?bid={$bid}&amp;id={$next_id['id']}'>NEXT</a>";
```

You need curly braces (`{}`) around object and array variables, but it is also useful for normal variables. Also, the array index should be in quotes as it is a string (not required for integer indexes).

Additionally, I changed the ampersand (`&`) to `&amp;` as `&` signifies the start of a special character code (just like `&amp;`), so although in this case it wouldn't be a problem it is best practice to put the HTML char code in, even in a URL.

Comment: Inside the `{}` the array key `[id]` _must be quoted_ or it will cause `undefined constant id`  notices. `{$next_id['id']}`

Comment: Ah yes, well spotted.